React seo optimisation
Why is the meta tag description not displaying in my React component using react-helmet? I have ensured that react-helmet is correctly installed and imported, but the meta tags are not visible in the browser's developer tools. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue?
import React from "react";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

const Test = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Helmet>
        <title>Updated Testing Software | Software Development</title>
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="Discover the latest testing software solutions for efficient software development. Find tools and techniques to streamline your testing processes."
        />
        <meta
          name="keywords"
          content="testing, software development, tools, techniques"
        />
        <link rel="canonical" href="/updated-testing-software" />
      </Helmet>
      <div>Beliving I'll get the answer</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Test;


Where is Test imported and used?

Bro, honestly what is Test?

React helmet won't help SEO at all.  Search engines need all the content, not just meta tags.  So either use SSR or rely on Googlebot and Bingbot's ability to render JavaScript.  Helmet's main use is enabling social media previews.

const Test = () => { this is the name of your component. Where do you import and use this component?
